# I want to replace some characters from a string. I used the Replace command. But this is not working

Tags: vb.net

I am writing some code in VB.Net to subtract one string from another string, but this is not working. in output nothing is changed in the target string. But there is no error message. Please help. Thanks.

```
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        positive = (TextBoxp1.Text + TextBoxp2.Text + TextBoxp3.Text)
        negative = (TextBoxn1.Text + TextBoxn2.Text + TextBoxn3.Text)

        findstring = Replace(positive, negative, "")
        TextBox1.Text = findstring
    End If
```

Comment: What are the strings you are placing in the various text boxes? What is the expected output in `TextBox1`?

Comment: Maybe you should start by giving your controls sensible, descriptive names.  As for the issue, that code does exactly what it does, so it is working perfectly.  If it doesn't do what you want done then you should write different code.  As you haven't actually provided a description of what you want done, it's rather hard for us to suggest what that code should be.  Have you even debugged that code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through the code to examine the state at each step?  If not, it's too soon to be posting here.  If so, you need to tell us what you saw.

Comment: When you are combining strings, use & instead of +

Comment: For starters, put `Option Strict On` at the top of your class file (better yet, always turn it on at the project level).  That will highlight the problem in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation symbol in vb.net is the ampersand (&). You may get unexpected results it you use the plus sign and the strings contain numbers. Parenthesis are not necessary to evaluate an expression except to establish order of calculation when it conflicts with order of precedence.

You are using the vb.net Strings.Replace method. I would use the .net String.Replace method because it is easier to move between .net languages when you get used to using .net methods instead of vb specific methods.
This method takes the original string in this case `negative` and looks for the entire `positive` string. If it finds the entire string it replaces it with the empty string.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim positive = "b" & "cd" & "ef"
    Dim negative = "abc" & "def" & "ghi"
    TextBox1.Text = negative.Replace(positive, "")
    'Result is aghi
End Sub
```

If you are trying to remove individual letters from a string then you will have to use a loop. Luckily for us a String is an array of Char.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim positive = "ceg"
    Dim negative = "abcdefg"
    For Each ch As Char In positive
        negative = negative.Replace(ch, "")
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = negative
    'Result abdf
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making this way too complicated.  If what you want is to remove a substring from within a string use replace like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    If rdbtnRemove.Checked Then
        txtResultString.Text = Replace(txtLargeString.Text, txtSearchString.Text, "")
    End If
End Sub
```

All you need is two radio buttons, three text boxes and a button.  If you enter 1121221114141 in the txtLargeString text box, 2122 in the txtSearchString text box and execute the code, the result is 111114141 which is the result of removing the txtSearchString input from the txtLargeString input.

Or if as @Mary suggested you want to use the more modern version of replace use this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    If rdbtnRemove.Checked Then
        txtResultString.Text = txtLargeString.Text.Replace(txtSearchString.Text, "")
    End If
End Sub
```